# Dynamically import d3.js as module?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6, import

Trying to dynamically import ("lazy-load") d3 as module from within my existing module to make it self-reliant, as per the es6 syntactic feature (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import#dynamic). The source at https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js includes no "export" statement, only a literal function call (

```
!function(t,n){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?n(exports):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],n):n(t.d3=t.d3||{})}(...)
```

), yet it does get retrieved, only it doesn't receive its parameters it would expect from a normal `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"/>` tag import. How do I manually provide them, or how am I rather supposed to do this? thanks!

```
import('https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js').then(function(d3){d3.json()})


d3.v5.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'd3' of undefined
at d3.v5.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*My first guess was wrong...*
This error happens because this build of `d3` is trying to read `this.d3` (the function argument that receives `this` is called `global`, or `t` in the minified version), but `this` is undefined in a module context (which a script runs in when `import`ed).

It is simply a bug in whatever build tool is used to produce this `d3` build. It should use `self` (or perhaps `this || self`).

`rollup` for example used to have this bug but it was fixed a while ago.

---

Regardless, even after `d3` is fixed, you won't get anything in `.then()`, it will set the `d3` global. (Unless they release an ES module build.)

Comment: Also, until a correct build of `d3` is released you can fix this for yourself by changing the first occurrence of `this` to `self` in `d3.v5.min.js`

Comment: perfect solution, thanks! gonna stick with a local copy of d3 than. also to anyone else conflicting this, beware of naming the returning Module parameter "d3", overwriting the global `d3` as in my attempt ;). ( `import('https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js').then(function(/*d3*/){d3.json()})` )

Comment: Worth filing an issue with `d3` too, if there isn't one already. + If the answer is correct could you accept it? :)